# WPF Chart Toolkit documentation

Tags: wpftoolkit, charts, codeplex

sorry for this stupid question, but I would like to know where it should be possible to find the documentation for the WPF CHART Toolkit, downloaded from http://wpf.codeplex.com/
At the moment, I've fould just blogs, and other post over Internet, but nothing like MSDN library...

Any help should be precious.

regards, Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation within MSDN can be found [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=58833) for a subset of the controls within the WPFToolkit. In addition the CodePlex site has an [area](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Links%20to%20Documentation) for referencing worthy documentation with regard to the WPFToolkit.